# Angular project needs to empty click to update screen after getting data from service

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

Angular project that gets **Data** from some **services** and makes some calculation with this data, then it shows in a component (Using Grid Component of the **Syncfusion**). When it comes to **ngOnInit**, data is loaded but it **doesn't appear** on page. Whenever I click to somewhere on screen it shows the data on page. I couldn't handle it, any suggestions ?

```
<ejs-grid #grid id='grid'[rowHeight]='30' (rowDataBound)="rowDataBound($event)" [dataSource]='XXX$ | async' [editSettings]='editSettings' (cellSaved)="dataChanged($event)" height="300px" style="color: red;">
            <e-columns>
                <e-column field='x1' [visible]="check[0]" headerText='x1' textAlign='center'  width=120></e-column>
                <e-column field='x2' [visible]="check[1]" headerText='x2' textAlign='center'  width=120></e-column>                    
                <e-column field='x3' [visible]="check[2]" headerText='x3' textAlign='center'  width=120></e-column>
            </e-columns>
</ejs-grid>
```

Binding dataSource **property** with an **observable** and passing data into this observable from an array with **"of()"** tag

```
XXX$!: Observable<XModel[]>;

this.XXX$= of(YYY);
```

Comment: You'll want to add a bit more code, for instance the component using the `dataSource` attribute.

Comment: Is there a service with API call involved? Would be helpful to include its use in the example - it's more than likely a timing issue (people often use cd.detectChanges as a workaround), but it's best to fix the underlying problem

Comment: I solved it with changeDetectionRef.detectChanges(), thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with changeDetectionRef.detectChanges().

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Add into constructor from imports,

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

Call detectChanges() where you need

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
```